# doesnt work when i declare it as parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

If i declare the Bind attribute as a parameter on the method, it doesnt work as it expected

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="ID")]int ServiceId, Event evnt)
        {
            var service = dbSrc.GetAll().WithID(ServiceId).SingleOrDefault();
            if (service == null)
```

But if i declare it on the class level, it works!

```
[Bind(Exclude = "ID")]
    partial class Event
    {
```

The form firing the create action is in the usercontrol and i am using asp.net mvc 1 ?

My db setup is fine. The id column is primary key and auto generated.

What might be the reason ? or it s a bug in the version 1.0 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int ServiceId, [Bind(Exclude="ID")]Event evnt)
```

instead? I'm betting `ServiceId` has no `ID` property.

Comment: Thanks Craig, it works! But what is the reason ? Is it because the custom parameters come first and then the model with Bind attirubute follows it ?

Comment: When you put `[Bind` *inside* the `()` on a method, you are putting the attribute on an *individual argument*, not on the whole method.